# How to use a method from one Form in another (or one class in another class) in C#

Tags: c#, methods, import, treeview, visual-studio-2013

So, I have a treeview in Form2. On a button click, in Form3 a code executes which inserts the text from the textboxes(from Form3) into the database, after that happens, I want the treeview in Form2 to update itself with those values from the database, which means I need to either use the treeView1(from Form2) in the code I write in Form3 or write a method in Form2(which I've done) to use in Form3.

Method in Form2:

```
    public static void LoadTree()
    {
        int j = 1;
        string var;
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand populate = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Project_name FROM Edit_Nodes ORDER BY Location ASC", con);
        OleDbDataReader reader = populate.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var = "H" + j + " - " + reader["Project_name"] + "";
            treeView1.Nodes[j].Text = var;
            j++;
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Problem : "Error    5   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Tool.Form2.con'" and so on for treeView1 and the other con's in the code.

Code in Form3:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // more code here

      Form2.LoadTree();
    }
```

My question is how to solve these errors, OR....how do I directly make the program recognise treeView1 in Form3 (it belonging to Form2) so I can write the code again there.

Comment: You can do something similar to databiding... take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990112/can-you-data-bind-a-treeview-control

Answer (score 0):

First, make it an instance method instead of static:

```
public void LoadTree()
{
    // implementation
}
```

The reason `static` doesn't work is because it doesn't have the context of any given instance of the form, so it doesn't have the context of the controls on any given instance (such as `treeView1`).  Next, you'll need the `Form3` instance to have a reference to that particular `Form2` instance.  An easy way to do this is to add a property to `Form3` and require a reference in its constructor.  So, in `Form3`:

```
private Form2 Form2Instance { get; set; }

public Form3(Form2 form2Instance)
{
    this.Form2Instance = form2Instance;
}
```

At this point any time you need to create an instance of `Form3`, you need to supply it an instance of `Form2`.  So if you create it from within `Form2` then you'd do something like this:

```
var form3Instance = new Form3(this);
form3Instance.Show();
```

At that point any instance of `Form3` has a reference to the instance of `Form2` which created it.  So your code on `Form3` can just reference the instance it has in that private property to call the method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // more code here
    this.Form2Instance.LoadTree();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being noobish but I don/t really know where to put the 2'nd code ( var form3Instance = new Form3(this); etc...I've put it in Form2 on the button press that makes Form3 appear, but now Form3 shows a blank form insteam of the one I designed, I've deleted the Form3 arguments : var form3Instance = new Form3(); and now it's ok but I get an excepton : An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Honeycomb Tool.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

after I press the button on Form3.

Comment: the exception is pointing to the code this.Form2Instance.LoadTree();

Comment: @VenomXLR: Well, the part where I create a new instance of `Form3` was mostly a guess, since I don't know how you're creating it now.  It's just an illustration of passing a reference to `Form2` upon the creation of `Form3`.  Maybe you can show how you create `Form3` currently?  The `NullReferenceException` will happen on that line if you never set `Form2Instance` to a value.

Comment: Well my Form3 is already created in the designer view, I'm starting it from the main form (Form2) on a button press(which I edited now with on your code, that is, remore "this" from arguments because of the exception):

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form3Instance = new Form3();
            form3Instance.Show();
        }

Comment: @VenomXLR: In that case where you call `var form3Instance = new Form3();` you'd pass it `this` like in my example.  As long as you've updated the `Form3` constructor to accept that reference as in my example it should work.  If it's still not working, maybe you can update your question with the new code and any error you're getting?

Comment: OK, I added that argument, no errors but my Form3 is blank when I click the button from Form2 to load it, my textboxes/buttons and all that I designed in Form3 are gone. I need it to load the already designed Form3. Btw if you have 5 minutes come to my laptop with teamviwer to solve this faster : id:954 554 628 / pass: 6644

Comment: @VenomXLR: Was there already an existing constructor that had some code in it to initialize the form?  If so then modifying that constructor would be preferred over creating a new one.

Comment: Well I created the Form3 in the designer view, no explicit code for creating it, please come to my PC with teamview if you can, I'm pretty new to VS and C# and don't know if I'm being explicit enough here, maybe you can understand it better if you see it(the code inside), id: 954 554 628 / pass: 6644

Answer (score 0):

There're many issues with your code, see my comments

```
  // Since you want to update treeView1 you should 
  // point out on which instance of Form1 the target treeView1 is.
  // That's why LoadTree() can't be static
  public void LoadTree() { // <- Not static!
    // Much better to use a local connection here
    //TODO: provide the right connection string here
    using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
      con.Open();

      // wrap all local IDisposable into using(...) {...}
      using (OleDbCommand populate = new OleDbCommand(con)) {
        // Format out your SQL for it to be readble
        populate.CommandText = 
          "  select Project_Name\n" + 
          "    from Edit_Nodes\n" +
          "order by Location asc";

        // wrap all local IDisposable into using(...) {...}
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = populate.ExecuteReader()) {
          // When updating visual controls prevent them from constant re-painting
          // and annoying blinking
          treeView1.BeginUpdate();

          try {  
            // What is "j"? No-one knows; "loop" is more readable
            int loop = 1;

            while(reader.Read()) {
              // "var" is unreadable, "nodeText" is clear
              String nodeText = "H" + loop.ToString() + " - " + reader["Project_Name"];

              // Check ranges: what if SQL returns more recods than treeView1's nodes? 
              if (loop >= treeView1.Nodes.Count) 
                break;

              treeView1.Nodes[loop].Text = nodeText;

              loop += 1;
            }
          finally {
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
          }  
        }  
      }
    }
```

Now, it's time to call `LoadTree()`; but for *which* `Form2` instance? Imagine, that you've opened *five* `Form2`'s. Now let's call `LoadTree()` for all `Form2` instances:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // Enumerating all open forms
  foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {
    Form2 source = form as Form2;

    // If the open form is Form2, call LoadTree
    if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, source))
      source.LoadTree();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your operating on something called 'treeView1' in your LoadTree() method. If this is part of the Form2 it will have to be static or you will have to call this method from an already instantiated object of it.

1. Make treeView1 static
2. Form2 form = new Form2();
   form.TreeView();

Comment: Making the `TreeView` control static will very likely cause more problems than it solves.  And calling the method on an *entirely new* instance of `Form2` will do nothing to the *original* instance of `Form2`.

Comment: I meant to call a new instance to show that it is actually an instantiated Form2